# Angular 7: @angular/core splitting and reducing app bundle size

Tags: angular, angular7

In updates dedicated to Angular 7 release, there was information on splitting the `@angular/core` into 418 or something packages. It's done to potentially reduce an app bundle size and cold start performance.

Now when Angular 7 has been released ([official announcement](https://blog.angular.io/version-7-of-angular-cli-prompts-virtual-scroll-drag-and-drop-and-more-c594e22e7b8c) and Github [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)), they don't provide any official information on the above feature.

Specifically, has it been even included in v7 release? Do we need to enable it manually and how to do it, if so, or this works automatically after updating an app to Angular 7?

**UPDATE**: Here are some unofficial links where I initially learned about this feature: [link 1](https://www.quora.com/Whats-new-in-Angular-7), [link 2](https://www.quora.com/Whats-new-in-Angular-7).

Comment: The downvoter apparently knows more than provided in those official links, so he\she believes everybody should be by default as smart as he\she is :) Maybe he\she checks out all the commits to `@angular` repo?

Comment: My *guess* would be that this is not released yet then, as I haven't been able to find any mention of this in documentation and I believe the Angular team would want to highlight any bundle size improvements. Do you have a source for where you learned of this potential change originally? That could be helpful to figuring it out if this was done in v7.

Comment: @Wrokar Unfortunately, I only read about this feature in some unofficial sources like [this](https://www.quora.com/Whats-new-in-Angular-7) and [this](https://artjoker.net/blog/when-will-angular-7-be-released-top-changes-coming-in-angular-7/). For me as a business app dev, this was actually the most wanted feature of v7.

Comment: This is not the final release this is an RC if im not mistaken

Comment: @PatricioVargas No, it's a first _release_ of v7. You can check it by `npm outdated`. Also, they have `rc` or `beta` in package names if it's some kind of pre-release.

Comment: @PatricioVargas No problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The Angular team maintains [a page](https://update.angular.io) for how to upgrade between Angular versions. From this page, it looks like you'll need to run `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core` in the console.</s>

From [a source](https://www.code-sample.com/2018/04/what-new-in-angular-7-features.html) referenced in the sources you provided, the feature of `@angular/core` being split was a joke.

> Most of the sites sharing below points but these are fake points. **Someone made up fake release notes as a joke but developers/peoples started treating it like it was true.**
>
> A.       Splitting of @angular/core
>
> B.      A new ng-compiler
>
> C.      A new @angular/mine
>
> D.      A new @aiStore

Comment: This is not actually answers the question. The same instructions to `update @angular/core` is there for updating from v5 to v6 (you can check it by choosing those versions in comboboxes).

Comment: Yeah, that's the command used to update `@angular/core`; It will be common between releases. If there are changes to `@angular/core` then that will get them for you. There would likely be instructions in that upgrade page if any further action were needed.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just guessing. Let's start from my first question in the original post: **has the `@angular/core` splitting feature been even included in v7 release?** It hasn't even been mentioned on any of those official pages I provided.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'm impressed by myself being unable to distinguish this joke from the real release notes :D